# Menu animation and hover state - simple jQuery solution (LavaLamp menu's idea)

Tags: jquery, html, css, lavalamp

I'm having the following issue with a primary site navigation menu. I have already reviewed some questions the editor suggets when asking the quetion, but none are the thing I'm looking for... I'm really sorry for making such a specific question.

**The DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/fYq6k/1/

**EXPLANATION:** the menu must have the current selected. BUT when you hover another `#menu li a` the current status must *go away* and appear on the hovered element. When hover is out, if there has been no click, the current status must return to the *real* current `#menu li a`

*Note:*

- it should be a solution based on as much CSS as possible and as less jQuery as posible. But I do understand the jQuery is necessary
- transition on the fiddle must be respected
- if it doesn't mean a butload of extra code, I'd like it to work with focus state also

**You're great guys, thanks a lot in advance for any help!**

Here's the code I made my self, of course, not working...

```
$(function(){
  $('#menu li a').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('current');
    },
    function() {  
      $(this).removeClass('current');
    }
  );
});
```

The CSS:

```
#menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 46px 11px 0;
  border-top: 9px solid #7d7c7c;
  font: normal 15px/1em Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #6a6868;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;

  transition: all .3s ease;
}

#menu li a.current, #menu li a:hover {
  padding: 38px 11px 0;
  border-top: 17px solid #e30613;
}
```

HTML (tipicall, valid HTML5 menu):

```
<header>
    <nav>
      <ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
        <li><a class="current" href="#">La Agencia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Que Hacemos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add one extra class 'real' like this

```
$(function(){
    $('#menu li a').hover(function(){
      $('.current').removeClass('current').addClass("real");
    },function(){
      $('.real').removeClass('real').addClass("current");   
    }
    );
});
```

and remove the 'real' class to return to current http://jsfiddle.net/fYq6k/2/
UPDATE
to work with focus

```
$(function(){
    $('.current').addClass("real");
    $('#menu li a').hover(function(){
          $('.current').removeClass('current');
        },function(){
          $('.current').removeClass('current');
          $('.real').addClass("current");   
        }
    ).focus(function(){
          $('.current').removeClass('current');
          $(this).addClass("current");
    }).blur(function(){
         $('.current').removeClass("current");
         $('.real').addClass("current"); 
    });
});
```

you need to do the same on the events focus and blur [http://jsfiddle.net/fYq6k/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/fYq6k/4/)
fix the bug using focus
to fix the flickering i add one empty div to every "li a" and animate that div instead of the border and padding
HTML

```
<ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
    <li><a class="current" href="#"><div></div>La Agencia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div></div>Que Hacemos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div></div>Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div></div>Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu li a div{
    height:9px;
    background:#7d7c7c;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
#menu li a.current div{
  height: 17px;
  background:#e30613;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fYq6k/6/

Comment: Awesome! Cannot believe it! Wordked like a charm! Now that you are on it... you'll notice that if you hover fast, the text flickers. That's because the effect is achieved when less top padding is applied and a mayor top border is applied, SO I guess that the effect calculation is perfect when hover effect is completely achieved BUT when you iterrupt it, the text goes down and up (kind of flickers)... I don't believe any client will actually do somthing like that, but if I can avoid it, the better! If you have any suggestions on how to do re-do it an achieve perfection... welcome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, using focus bugs the nav... Check it out

Comment: Incredible! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found this example page: http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/249/index.html
In it, the selection returns to the "home" when the mouse is not hovering over the menu.
There's also a tutorial for it. It does not contain any javascript I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I've already seen this and it is not what I need.